# What is limit of json array and how to overcome it

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to make a JSON array than can store 500 JSON objects. It works fine for few records but after that it's left as incomplete.

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();

for(int g=0;g<500;g++)
{
    JSONObject object =new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("name", g + "");
        object.put("mobile", g + "");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
    array.put(object);
}
```

Here's what I get:

```
2019-08-03 23:22:36.915 12718-12718/com.example.daac E/hello: [{"name":"0","mobile":"0"},{"name":"1","mobile":"1"},{"name":"2","mobile":"2"},{"name":"3","mobile":"3"},{"name":"4","mobile":"4"},{"name":"5","mobile":"5"},{"name":"6","mobile":"6"},{"name":"7","mobile":"7"},{"name":"8","mobile":"8"},{"name":"9","mobile":"9"},{"name":"10","mobile":"10"},{"name":"11","mobile":"11"},{"name":"12","mobile":"12"},{"name":"13","mobile":"13"},{"name":"14","mobile":"14"},{"name":"15","mobile":"15"},{"name":"16","mobile":"16"},{"name":"17","mobile":"17"},{"name":"18","mobile":"18"},{"name":"19","mobile":"19"},{"name":"20","mobile":"20"},{"name":"21","mobile":"21"},{"name":"22","mobile":"22"},{"name":"23","mobile":"23"},{"name":"24","mobile":"24"},{"name":"25","mobile":"25"},{"name":"26","mobile":"26"},{"name":"27","mobile":"27"},{"name":"28","mobile":"28"},{"name":"29","mobile":"29"},{"name":"30","mobile":"30"},{"name":"31","mobile":"31"},{"name":"32","mobile":"32"},{"name":"33","mobile":"33"},{"name":"34","mobile":"34"},{"name":"35","mobile":"35"},{"name":"36","mobile":"36"},{"name":"37","mobile":"37"},{"name":"38","mobile":"38"},{"name":"39","mobile":"39"},{"name":"40","mobile":"40"},{"name":"41","mobile":"41"},{"name":"42","mobile":"42"},{"name":"43","mobile":"43"},{"name":"44","mobile":"44"},{"name":"45","mobile":"45"},{"name":"46","mobile":"46"},{"name":"47","mobile":"47"},{"name":"48","mobile":"48"},{"name":"49","mobile":"49"},{"name":"50","mobile":"50"},{"name":"51","mobile":"51"},{"name":"52","mobile":"52"},{"name":"53","mobile":"53"},{"name":"54","mobile":"54"},{"name":"55","mobile":"55"},{"name":"56","mobile":"56"},{"name":"57","mobile":"57"},{"name":"58","mobile":"58"},{"name":"59","mobile":"59"},{"name":"60","mobile":"60"},{"name":"61","mobile":"61"},{"name":"62","mobile":"62"},{"name":"63","mobile":"63"},{"name":"64","mobile":"64"},{"name":"65","mobile":"65"},{"name":"66","mobile":"66"},{"name":"67","mobile":"67"},{"name":"68","mobile":"68"},{"name":"69","mobile":"69"},{"name":"70","mobile":"70"},{"name":"71","mobile":"71"},{"name":"72","mobile":"72"},{"name":"73","mobile":"73"},{"name":"74","mobile":"74"},{"name":"75","mobile":"75"},{"name":"76","mobile":"76"},{"name":"77","mobile":"77"},{"name":"78","mobile":"78"},{"name":"79","mobile":"79"},{"name":"80","mobile":"80"},{"name":"81","mobile":"81"},{"name":"82","mobile":"82"},{"name":"83","mobile":"83"},{"name":"84","mobile":"84"},{"name":"85","mobile":"85"},{"name":"86","mobile":"86"},{"name":"87","mobile":"87"},{"name":"88","mobile":"88"},{"name":"89","mobile":"89"},{"name":"90","mobile":"90"},{"name":"91","mobile":"91"},{"name":"92","mobile":"92"},{"name":"93","mobile":"93"},{"name":"94","mobile":"94"},{"name":"95","mobile":"95"},{"name":"96","mobile":"96"},{"name":"97","mobile":"97"},{"name":"98","mobile":"98"},{"name":"99","mobile":"99"},{"name":"100","mobile":"100"},{"name":"101","mobile":"101"},{"name":"102","mobile":"102"},{"name":"103","mobile":"103"},{"name":"104","mobile":"104"},{"name":"105","mobile":"105"},{"name":"106","mobile":"106"},{"name":"107","mobile":"107"},{"name":"108","mobile":"108"},{"name":"109","mobile":"109"},{"name":"110","mobile":"110"},{"name":"111","mobile":"111"},{"name":"112","mobile":"112"},{"name":"113","mobile":"113"},{"name":"114","mobile":"114"},{"name":"115","mobile":"115"},{"name":"116","mobile":"116"},{"name":"117","mobile":"117"},{"name":"118","mobile":"118"},{"name":"119","mobile":"119"},{"name":"120","mobile":"120"},{"name":"121","mobile":"121"},{"name":"122","mobile":"122"},{"name":"123","mobile":"123"},{"name":"124","mobile":"124"},{"name":"125","mobile":"125"},{"name":"126","mobile":"126"},{"name":"127","mobile":"127"},{"name":"128","mobile":"128"},{"name":"129","mobile":"129"},{"name":"130","mobile":"130"},{"name":"131","mobile":"131"},{"name":"132","mobile":"132"},{"name":"133","mobile":"133"},{"name":"134","mobile":"134"},{"name":"135","mobile":"135"},{"name":"136","mobile":"136"},{"name":"137","mobile":"137"},{"name":"138","mobile":"138"},{"name":"139","mobile":"139"},{"name":"140","mobile":"140"},{"name":"141","mobile":"141"},{"name":"142","mobi
```

Why it is empty and what is the solution for that?

Comment: You need to identify which language you are using. Is this Java?

Comment: The blank Exception handler is going to disable any diagnostics explaining what went wrong. You will want to take that out.

Comment: There is no such limit. Instead of printing the `array` or `array.toString()` print `array.length()` and you'll see nothing is lost even for `500000` objects.

Comment: Hey, there is a limitation of log print in a single line so it is not showing complete. You print the same in any  TextView under scrollview and you will see it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such limit. Instead of printing the `array` or `array.toString()` print `array.length()` and you'll see nothing is lost even for `500000` `JSONObject`. Of course, more objects you add to the `JSONArray` more heap space it occupies and till the time heap space is available you may keep on adding JSONObject to the JSONArray.

The truncated output you have shown may be a limitation of console or device and runtime environment (android).

Does not look like an exception occurred (JSONArray won't contain invalid JSON) however, either log or print the stack trace (`e.printStackTrace()`) in the exception block to understand the scenario and as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray have no such limits, but in your case the logs are getting truncated because of the console's length limitation.

Try printing log for each JSONObject entry using for loop and you will get all the records.

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject rec = array.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(rec.getString("name"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation of Log. Console prints the log for a certain characters which is the result of your case. Your code for creating JSON is absolutely fine. You print the same in any TextView under a scrollable area and you will get the complete JSON string.